# My script does not search all links, what to do?

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup

I'm building a script to scan a website and capture URLs and test whether it's working or not. The problem is that the script is looking for just the URLs of the website's home page and leaving others aside. How do I capture all pages linked to the site?

Below my code attachment:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError


page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features='lxml')
links = soup.findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile('^(http://)')})
for link in links:

    result = (link["href"])

    req = Request(result)

    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        pass

    except HTTPError as e:

        if e.code != 200:
            # Stop, Error!
            with open("Document_ERROR.txt", 'a') as archive:
               archive.write(result)
               archive.write('\n')
               archive.write('{} \n'.format(e.reason))
               archive.write('{}'.format(e.code))
               archive.close()
        
        else:
        # Enjoy!
            with open("Document_OK.txt", 'a') as archive:
               archive.write(result)
               archive.write('\n')
               archive.close()
```

Comment: _not exploring external and internal_ What do you mean?

Comment: those links linked to the page. The internal is the site

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The proposal was to look for broken links on the site. In the search it only finds the URLs linked to the home page and does not scan the other sites.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would do that. I might be missing something, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just want help with this

Comment: Help with that specifically?

Comment: I wanted to make a script that could search for a broken link on the code's website, it is looking for URLs from the site's initial page. So I want to know how to somehow fix this problem.

Comment: Right, but is there anything to fix currently, have you written any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason this doesn't work is that you put both the OK and ERROR-writes inside the except-block.

This means that only urls that actually raise an exception will be stored.

In general it would be my advice for you to spray some print-statements into the difference stages of the script - or use an IDE that allows you to step through the code during runtime - line by line. That makes stuff like this so much easier to debug.

PyCharm is free and allows you to do so. Give that a try.

So - I haven't worked with urllib but use requests a lot (python -m pip install requests). A quick refactor using that would look something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

url = "http://www.google.com"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

links = soup.find_all("a", attrs={'href': re.compile('^(http://)')}) 

for link in links: 
    href = link["href"]
    print("Testing for URL {}".format(href))
    
    try:
        # since you only want to scan for status code, no need to pull the entire html of the site - use HEAD instead of GET
        r = requests.head(href)
        status = r.status_code
        # 404 etc will not yield an error
        error = None
    except Exception as e:
        # these exception will not have a status_code
        status = None
        error = e
    
    # store the finding in your files
    if status is None or status != 200:
        print("URL is broken. Writing to ERROR_Doc")
        # do your storing here of href, status and error
    else:
        print("URL is live. Writing to OK_Doc"
        # do your storing here
```

Hope this makes sense.